# Using Linq or Lambda to compare items in nested collections

Tags: c#, linq, list, lambda, nested-lists

I have an object which looks something like this

**Object**

- Name
- ID
- PropertyGroupList[]

  - **PropertyGroupListItem**

    - PropertyList[]

      - **PropertyListItem**

        - Tag
        - Type
      - **PropertyListItem**

        - Tag
        - Type
  - **PropertyGroupListItem**

    - PropertyList[]

      - **PropertyListItem**

        - Tag
        - Type
      - **PropertyListItem**

        - Tag
        - Type

Each of those objects has a PropertyListItem where the Tag is "Revision". I need to compare the value of "Revision" with all of the other objects stored in the list and return the item where "Revision" has the highest value.

I think I can build a way with nested `for` loops but I thought it would be a better approach to get the Object by using a Linq or Lambda expression.

I've been trying to find a way to do this by myself but I feel like everything I did is completely wrong. I'd be more than happy if someone could help me and give a little explanation about it. Thanks a lot!

EDIT:

Sample code:

```
    public MdsObject GetSoftwareObjectByName(string sPackageName)
    {
        GetObjectListRequest getObjectListReq = new GetObjectListRequest();
        InitializeRequest(getObjectListReq);
        //TODO: Are there more characters which need to be escaped in an LDAP query to DSM?
        sPackageName = sPackageName.Replace("(", "\\(");
        sPackageName = sPackageName.Replace(")", "\\)");
        getObjectListReq.LdapQuery = "<LDAP://rootDSE>;(Name:IgnoreCase=" + sPackageName + ");;subtree";
        getObjectListReq.MaxResults = -1;
        GetObjectListReply getObjectListReply = AdministrationService.GetObjectList(getObjectListReq);

        switch (getObjectListReply.ObjectList.Length)
        {
            case 0:
                { throw new ApplicationException("GetSoftwareObjectByName failed. Could not find '" + sPackageName + "'"); }
            case 1:
                {
                    MdsObject incompleteObjectFromLdap = getObjectListReply.ObjectList[0];
                    return GetSoftwareObjectById(incompleteObjectFromLdap.ID);
                }
                //more than one object was returned -> check revisions
            default:
                {
                    List<MdsObject> ListReturnedObjects = new List<MdsObject>();

                    for (int i = 1; i <= getObjectListReply.ObjectList.Length; i++)
                    {
                        MdsObject incompleteObjectFromLdap = getObjectListReply.ObjectList[i-1];
                        ListReturnedObjects.Add(GetSoftwareObjectById(incompleteObjectFromLdap.ID));
                    }

                    **Here I need to filter the objects**

                    throw new ApplicationException("GetSoftwareObjectByName failed. Software name '" + sPackageName + "' is not unique!");
                }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It would be much easier to help you with sample code, sample input and sample output...

Comment: what is the best way to copy the object from visual studio and keep everything readable?

Answer (score 0):

First Start off by flatening your nested hierarchy down to an IEnumerable

```
var q = MyObject.PropertyGroupList
    .SelectMany(item=>item.PropertyList); // For every Item in the GroupList, Flatten it and return the individual PropertyListItem
```

Then find the one with the highest revision

```
var q2 = q.OrderbyDescending(item=>item.Tag) // Order them by tag starting with the largest
    .First(); // And get the first and thus biggest one.
```